# Checking DB for existing record with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to check if the database has the record to prevent duplicates. I am using the following code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE useremail=:useremail');
    $stmt->bindParam(':useremail', $_GET['useremail'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($row) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Swal.fire('Info', 'This email is already registered.','info')";
    } else {
        $kaydet = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter SET useremail=:useremail");
        $insert = $kaydet->execute(array('useremail' => $_POST['useremail']));

        if ($insert) {
            header("Location:../index.php?status=success");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location:../index.php?status=error");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

I aim to prevent form submission for duplicate records. But this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You're using `PDO::PARAM_INT` when binding a string? Have you tried `PDO::PARAM_STR` (or removing it completely since it defaults to string)? You're also using `$_GET['useremail']` for the first query and `$_POST['useremail']` in the second. Which is it? You also never close the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with doing `SELECT`, check result, do `INSERT`, in PHP is that it is subject to race conditions. One thread could be about to do the `insert` just as the other `select`s no rows and about to also do an `insert`, and now you have duplicates.

When confronted with this situation, let the database handle it.

A unique index on `useremail` (or primary key), for the table will resolve this.

Attempt the insert, if you get a duplicate key exception, then that's when you fire `'This email is already registered.'`, otherwise its a successful addition.

Answer (score -2):

i think the problem is with the

```
$stmt->bindParam(':useremail', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Use above instead of param int
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: The colon is optional there. There are several other issues with their code.

Comment: if just revisted the code the problem is with bind param statement